# An empty string was turned into null in mybatis?

Tags: java, mybatis

code 1.

```
private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";
```

code 2.

```
criteria.andAppVersionEqualTo(EMPTY_STRING);
```

code 3.

```
public Criteria andAppVersionEqualTo(String value) {
    addCriterion("app_version =", value, "appVersion");
    return (Criteria) this;
}
```

I debug code 2, I find the value become null when it run to code 3.

The XXExample class was generated by mybatis with

and table field "app_version" in DB is not allow null.

So, anyone knows why? and how to fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: generatorConfiguration: targetRuntime="MyBatis3"

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  Oracle (at least older versions) does not differentiate between null and empty strings.

Comment: Mysql 5.6.34 + Sequel Pro 1.1.2
I restart tomcat and service, and it works now!
Thanks anyway, bro!